# how to display the indexPath value

Tags: iphone

my question is how can i display the value of the selected item in a UITableView
(index or the text value) in NSLog
i want to test on this value to select the right view
thanks for your help

Answer (score 15):

NSIndexPath has convenience int properties (section, row) for usage with UITableView, you can log them as follows:

```
NSLog(@"Section: %d, Row: %d", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mr Vladimir

Answer (score 1):

you can just use

```
NSLog (@"%@", indexPath);
```

or if you are passing your indexPath to a NSIndexPath variable you can just replace indexPath with your variable name

```
NSLog (@"%@", myIndexPath);
```

your output should look like this

```
2011-10-07 09:32:16.996 myCode[3439:207] <NSIndexPath 0x4e3aeb0> 2 indexes [0, 3]
2011-10-07 09:32:16.997 myCode[3439:207] <NSIndexPath 0x4e3aeb0> 2 indexes [0, 3]
```

> [Section, row]